# VueJS mounted hook in v-on directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I call a method in VueJS when some html elements are mounted?

For example:

```
...
data: [
  {
    items: [
      {text:'item1'},
      {text:'item2'}
    ]
  }
]
methods: function() {
  myMethod: function(a) {
    console.warn(a)
  }
}
template: '<div
             v-for="item in items"
             :key="item.text"
             @hook:mounted="myMethod(item.text + \" mounted\")"
           >{{ item.text }}</div>'
...
```

I need to get HTML like this:

```
<div>item1</div>
<div>item2</div>
```

And I need to get 2 warn messages in console:

```
item1 mounted
item2 mounted
```

Or I can do it with another way?

Comment: For example I have ```data: {items:[{text:"item1"},{text:"item2"}]}``` and I need to loop it by v-for directive my HTML element. Each element will warn own message like 'item1 mounted', 'item2 mounted' and so om

Comment: What does `v-for` have to do with `mounting`? Component mounting should occur before any `v-for` loop is even executed. It's not possible at all to do this using a lifecycle-hook directive ( AKA @hook)

Comment: You're going to need to explain that a bit better, I can't understand what you are trying to do at all.. if you're just trying to add the text `'mounted'` to each item's `text` what does that have to do with the `mounted` Vue lifecycle hook? You need to revise your question to include an example of what you expect or more details.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You should really read my answer. You cannot call the `mounted` hook on an `HTMLElement`, `div` is *not* a **Vue Component**, `div` is an `HTMLElement`. It does **not** have life-cycle hooks (`mounted`, `created`, `destroyed`, etc...). What you are trying to do is not possible period, `div`'s are not **mounted** they are **rendered**. The moment the `div` is rendered, you can consider it `mounted`, so you may as well just change your template to say `item1 mounted` from start instead of trying to wait for a life-cycle hook that will never happen because it doesn't exist.

Comment: The only alternative is to create a Vue component with a template that is just a `div`. **Then** you could subscribe to the `mounted()` hook.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you, but HOW can I reach goal in the question without creating a component?

Comment: Your goal isn't possible with an HTML Element. Create a Vue component wrapper for a div, use the Vue component and subscribe to its `mounted` event

Comment: Thank you. I am new to VueJS and sometimes I look for more ways to do the thing. And I agree that it's maybe a little bit hard to explain the thing to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the `hook:mounted` event is only available for components and won't fire for HTML elements.

You can do something similar for elements using a custom directive. While an element can't be 'mounted' we can nevertheless have a directive that is called when the element is available.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  directives: {
    myMountedDirective (el, { value }) {
      console.warn(value + ' mounted')
    }
  },

  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {text: 'item1'},
        {text: 'item2'}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.text"
    v-my-mounted-directive="item.text"
  >
    {{ item.text }}
  </div>
</div>
```

However, all of this is very DOM-driven. Custom directives exist so that tweaks can be made to the DOM nodes after they exist. Generally that isn't the correct way to solve the underlying problem.

Usually it is better to make decisions based on the data rather than the DOM. So rather than watching for changes to the DOM we can watch for changes in `items`.

If you really do need access to the DOM nodes (e.g. to measure sizes) then you might be better off using refs. You can add a `ref` attribute to each `<div>` and they will then be accessible as an array via `$refs`. The `mounted` and `updated` hooks of the surrounding component are generally the appropriate places to react to changes in the `$refs` as they all called immediately after rendering.

Comment: Oh, in my situation that's best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the `@hook:mounted` syntax adds a life-cycle hook to a **Vue Component**.

`<div></div>` is a plain HTML element.. you need to add a `mounted()` method to your component options. The reason `@click` works and `@hook` doesn't is because HTML elements have click events; they don't have Vue component lifecycle hooks.

EDIT: To demonstrate, go ahead and visit [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/18r05pkmn7), navigate to `App.vue` and try to move the `@hook:mounted` directive from the `Child` component to the `div` that contains it, you'll notice the hook is never called because `div` has no life-cycle hooks

EDIT: Also your Vue component needs to look like this:

```
mounted: function(a) {
    this.myMethod("Hello, I am mounted!");
},
methods: {
  myMethod(a) { console.warn(a); }
},
template: '<div></div>'
```

Comment: does this work with composition api?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to simulate a component mounting on `div`s is to actually create a component that **is** a div:

**V-Div.vue**

```
<template>
 <div><slot></slot></div>
</template>
```

You need a `<slot>` so that you can pass content into the `<v-div>`

Include V-Div in your component (the component *you* created, not V-Div.vue)

```
import VDiv from './components/V-Div.vue';
// ...
{
  data() { return { /* data */} },
  computed: {},
  // other options....
  components: {VDiv}
}
```

Use the `VDiv` in your component template:

```
<v-div @hook:mounted="myMethod(item.text + \" mounted\")">{{item.text}}</v-div>
```

EDIT: I would not recommend doing this, turning a plain HTML Element into a Vue component just to subscribe to life-cycles is a waste of resources.